# Translate all files and save in in another directory - Python

Tags: python

I've got a lot of .txt files. I want to open them all in sequential manner, translate via Google Translate and save with the same name, but in another directory.

My code is simple, its print a text within all files, but it translate and rewrite only the last file. How can I fix it?

```
from googletrans import Translator
import os
import glob

translator = Translator()

folder_path = 'G:\python'
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.txt')):
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(text)
result = translator.translate(text, dest='fr')
print(result.text)
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
  f.write(result.text)
```

Comment: There are two problems: 1) The `write` method isn't in the loop (so it's using the last iteration only) and 2) You don't seem to be saving with the same name in **another directory** If you only fix #1, you'll overwrite all the original content so be careful.

Comment: The line `result = translator.translate(text, dest='fr')` and everything below it should be indented one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take a look at your indent;

```
from googletrans import Translator
import os
import glob

translator = Translator()

folder_path = os.path.join('G:','python')
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '**','*.txt'), recursive=True):
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(text)
  result = translator.translate(text, dest='fr')
  print(result.text)
  with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(result.text)
    f.flush()
```

Comment: I also added recursive file search